# Kernel refusing to free up disk cache

Tags: debian, kernel, linux-kernel, memory, virtual-memory

I have ~20GB of RAM and ~4GB of swap on my machine. Around 8GB of memory is used by applications, the rest is used for disk space by the kernel. Over time, the swap fills up completely and then something gets oom-killed.

First I thought, that something wanted to allocate a huge amount of RAM and caused the OOM, but now it happened due to me opening a tiny file in VIM. So that can't be the reason.

My only explanation is, that the kernel is refusing to free disk cache when the applications need more RAM, but I don't know how this could be happening.
I already have `vm.vfs_cache_pressure = 200` and when I do `echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` nothing is freed.

As this is a production system, it has accumulated quite a lot of uptime (188 days). It is running a Debian Buster (kernel `4.19.0-10-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.132-1 (2020-07-24)`).

Is there any setting that prevents the kernel from releasing memory that is used for the disk-cache or any condition that can cause this behavior?
I'd be grateful for any idea about what could be causing this.

**Edit 1:**
I have rebooted the machine, and now I'm able to free a considerable part of the disk cache by `echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`. It seems that some "orphaned" something blocked the cache. What might that be?

Comment: Do you have any tmpfses mounted, *e.g.* for `/tmp`? If so, how big are they?

Comment: @StephenKitt there is one for `/run/` which 1.7M but I have quite a few docker containers running in swarm, can that be a cause?